# C# Collage of Pictures in a Content Place Holder

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to organize 12 pictures in a collage 3 x 4.  Currently, I am just inserting the images and resizing them to fit.  That worked fine, until I wanted to start the second row.  It started a new paragraph and there's a large space between them, and I want them all to touch.  How do I prevent this?  Or should I be using something else to organize the pics?

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms, WPF, Web Forms, MVC, Xamarin Forms...?

Comment: #Alex...Web Forms

Comment: Thanks - I've added that tag for you - please remember to mention/tag the tech you're using so that others can answer the question.

Comment: It's a css question. Post some code. Thanks

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)